# Should I change env vars to use the npm script under Cygwin in Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, cygwin, isparta

Should I change env vars to be able to use npm script under Cygwin in Windows?

When attempting to use the npm script under Cygwin in Windows, I receive the following error:

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
     ^
 Error: Cannot find module '/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/npm/isparta'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
     at Object.<anonymous>       (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\babel\lib\_babel-node.js:144:25)
     at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
     at startup (node.js:136:18)
```

I use node v4.2.2 with npm 2.14.7.

I ran the following command:

```
babel-node `which isparta` cover --include 'lib/**/*.js' _mocha -- 'test/**/*.spec.js' --reporter spec --ui tdd --recursive
```

I have installed successfully isparta, babel-node:

Sparta from cygwin terminal:

```
$ which isparta
/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/npm/isparta
```

Sparta from windows cmd:

```
C:\Users>where isparta
C:\ProgramData\npm\isparta
C:\ProgramData\npm\isparta.cmd
```

babel-node from cygwin terminal:

```
$ which babel-node
/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/npm/babel-node
```

babel-node from windows cmd:

```
C:\Users>where babel-node
C:\ProgramData\npm\babel-node
C:\ProgramData\npm\babel-node.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert Cygwin pathname to windows one, because apparently babel-node expects windows pathname:

```
babel-node `cygpath -w $(which isparta)` cover...
```